# Переполнение в типе char

Tags: char, c

Программа, описанная ниже, выводит -51 и 110.

У типа char диапазон -128 от 127. В памяти занимает 8 бит. Посчитал все, как полагается, в двоичной системе, посчитал переполнение с числом 205, получается вручную -49, никак не -51.

Объясните, пожалуйста, как получается -51, скорее даже как это происходит, скажем, "внутри компьютера"?

```
int main (void)
{
    char x=5,n=10;
    for(x+=100;x>0;x+=100);
    n+=100;
    printf("%i,%i",x,n);
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: @rokket_gc, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Для выполнения сложения `char` преобразуется в `int` или (очень редко) `unsigned int` ("integer promotion").

Пример в вопросе не о переполнении `char`, а о сужающем преобразовании из `int` типа в `char`.

`char` в зависимости от реализации может быть типом со знаком или без знака (implementation-defined).

Преобразование для типов без знака таких как `unsigned char` определено в стандарте как арифметика по остатку максимального значения плюс один, например, если `UCHAR_MAX` равен `255`, то

```
(unsigned char)205 + 100 == (int)305 == 305 - (UCHAR_MAX + 1) == 305 - 256 == 
(unsigned char)49
```

Если `char` тип имеет знак, то результат зависит от реализации (implementation-defined), например, в реализации, использующей ту же арифметику "по остатку":

```
(signed char)105 + 100 == (int)205 == 205 - 256 == (signed char)-51
```

Если сумма (`char`+`int`) не представима в типе `int` (integer overflow), то поведение не определено (bounded undefined behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вы не то насчитали. `205 - 267 = -51`.

Считайте, что число есть вычет по модулю 256, а его точный тип (signed или unsigned char) определяет лишь канонического представителя.

То есть, 256, а не 267. `205 - 256 = -51`. Ну вы поняли.